# How to make eager loading?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, eager-loading

How can I make eager loading between 1 primary key table and 2 foreign key tables?

say I have Table A (Primary)

Table A
   Id INT
   Name

Table B
   Id INT
   aID INT

Table C
   Id INT
   aID INT

Comment: What is "eager loading" in the context of database queries?  Just let the database handle the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's an entity framework thing. Whether or not the ORM retrieves the data for related entities up front or when required.

Comment: There is a ton of intro stuff on [EF eager vs lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx) out here, but your code sample implies you are trying to do SQL, which is very different.

Comment: `Context.A.Include(Function(a) a.B).Include(Function(a) a.C).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

I think all you need to do is to write a *single* query on all the tables:

```
select . ..
from a join
     b
     on b.aid = a.id join
     c
     on c.aid = a.id;
```

The database engine then manages the storage and can intelligently load pages into the page cache and keep them cached for future queries.

If you try to split this into multiple queries, then I don't see a way that one query on `a` would result in the corresponding rows of `b` being loaded.  On the other hand, how large are the tables?  If they are not large, the tables will be loaded into the page cache entirely and you won't have to worry about individual rows.

The one issue is that an initial query would be on a cold cache and take longer than subsequent queries.